# ReactJS - children on specific place

Tags: reactjs, children

I'm new to React and I'm building something like Card component from bootstrap. So what I want to achieve is create some  component with Children components like ,  etc ...

Is there any way to tell React where to render component of specific type (according name of component itself for example) to be able to do something like:

```
<Card>
   <CardHeader />
   <CardBody />
   ...
</Card>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain `state` to render component on condition,

```
state={
   cardHeader: true,
   cardBody: true
}
```

Now you can render component on condition,

```
<Card>
   {this.state.cardHeader && <CardHeader />}
   {this.state.cardBody && <CardBody />} 
   ...
</Card>
```

If you have button and onclick of that button you want card header to get disabled, you can do so,

```
<button onClick={this.hideCardHeader}>Hide Header</button>
```

```
hideCardHeader = () => {
   this.setState({cardHeader:false})
}
```

Doing this you can tell react you don't want to display card header.

**Note: You can render any component at any place. Where you place component at that place the component will get render.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer :)

I was trying different approach and I came up with something like this. It's probably not final and It requires some "fine-tuning" but It seems to be what I was looking for.

```
class Card extends Component {
    getParsedChildren = () => {
        const children = this.props.children;
        let header, body;
        
        children.forEach((child) => {
            switch(child.type) {
                case CardHeader:
                    header = child
                    break;
                case CardBody:
                    body = child
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        })

        return {header, body};
    }

    render() { 
        const {header, body} = this.getParsedChildren();
        
        return (
            <div className="card">
                {header}
                {body}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Card;
```

Is there anything wrong with the "design" ?

Thank you